# How to Replace dot (.) in a string in Java

Tags: java, str-replace

I have a String called `persons.name`

I want to replace the DOT `.` with `/*/`  i.e my output will be `persons/*/name`

I tried this code:

```
String a="\\*\\";
str=xpath.replaceAll("\\.", a);
```

I am getting StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.

How do I replace the dot?

Comment: I know that's an old question, but ad advice for everyone getting here: please, stop using replaceAll where you do not have to deal with regex. "replaceAll" doesn't mean "replace all occurrencies", in Java libraries.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

You need two backslashes before the dot, one to escape the slash so it gets through, and the other to escape the dot so it becomes literal.  Forward slashes and asterisk are treated literal.

```
str=xpath.replaceAll("\\.", "/*/");          //replaces a literal . with /*/
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: shouldn't it be `xpath.replaceAll("\\\\.", "/*/")` ?

Answer (score 18):

If you want to replace a simple string and you don't need the abilities of regular expressions, you can just use [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-), not `replaceAll`.

`replace` replaces each matching substring but does not interpret its argument as a regular expression.

```
str = xpath.replace(".", "/*/");
```

Answer (score 9):

Use [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/):

```
String a= "\\*\\";
str = StringUtils.replace(xpath, ".", a);
```

or with standalone JDK:

```
String a = "\\*\\"; // or: String a = "/*/";
String replacement = Matcher.quoteReplacement(a);
String searchString = Pattern.quote(".");
String str = xpath.replaceAll(searchString, replacement);
```

Answer (score -2):

return sentence.replaceAll("\s",".");

Comment: This is not what the question is asking for.