# How To replace character in android?

Tags: java, android, str-replace

I am try to replace character where come"." it should be replace by "". but its not working for me. please anyone tell me what i am missing in my code?

```
       // that variable is define publically
        public class QuizActivity extends Activity {
        private static String ans = null;
        int j = 0;

     //here some functionality

   next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                 empty();
                                 checkbox_enable();
                                 Custom_checkbox();

                                final int arraysize = data.size();

                                    j++;
                                if(j<arraysize){

                                     String Quiz_no = data.get(j).getQuiz_no();
                                     String Question = data.get(j).getQuestion();
                                     op1 = data.get(j).getAnswer_1().trim().toString();
                                     ans = data.get(j).getAns().trim();
                                     String answer=ans.toString();


                                     for (int k = 0; k < answer.length(); k++) {

                                        if (answer.charAt(k) == '.') {


                                            answer.replace(".", "");



                                        }if (answer.charAt(k) == ' ') {

                                            answer.replace(" ", "");
                                   String temp = answer;
                                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "replaced   "+temp,

 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                    }
```

please anyone help me . it is not working for me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380626/how-to-replace-dot-in-a-string-in-java

Comment: You need to store output of  `answer.replace(".", "");`  in some variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `replace` or `replaceAll` doesn't overwrite on the string.
You should use:

```
answer = answer.replaceAll(".", "");
answer = answer.replaceAll(" ", "");
```

Comment: not replace, not working @Burak Day

Comment: @saim check new answer

Comment: its Working for me now @Burak Day

Answer (score 1):

simply use `replaceAll` on String you want to replace.

**For Example**

```
String test = "hello.say.something";
test.replaceAll(".","");
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),test,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

> Result : hellosaysomething

Happy coding..

Answer (score 1):

A possible duplicate of [How to Replace dot (.) in a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380626/how-to-replace-dot-in-a-string-in-java).

So, instead of looping through your answer-string and checking each character, you can simply use `.replaceAll`. So change your code into something like this:

```
...
if(j<arraysize){
  String Quiz_no = data.get(j).getQuiz_no();
  String Question = data.get(j).getQuestion();
  op1 = data.get(j).getAnswer_1().trim().toString();
  ans = data.get(j).getAns().trim();
  String answer=ans.toString();
  //no need to loop through answer-string
  answer = answer.replaceAll(".","");
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: not working still @ishmaelMakitla

Comment: Edited the code - `answer = answer.replaceAll(".","");` - this should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You should know that `Strings` are immutable, so you need to store the output of `answer.replace(".", "");` in some new variable or to the same variable, So do like this

```
 String replacedString = null;

 for (int k = 0; k < answer.length(); k++) {
    if (answer.charAt(k) == '.') {
        replacedString = answer.replace(".", "");

    }if (answer.charAt(k) == ' ') {
        replacedString  = answer.replace(" ", "");
    }
}
```

**OR**

```
answer = answer.replace(".", "");
```